# .htaccess directory exception

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Right now, my current .htaccess in my root directory looks like this;

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule !^Email-Blasts($|/) http://example.com/store/%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/store/$
RewriteRule (.*) /store/ [R=301,L]
```

I am looking for any going to example.com/ to goto example.com/store/ but allow access to /email-blasts/ so the images and files within that directory work as well. Is this the correct way to go about it? Because it sure doesn't seem like it's working!

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your rule with this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(store|Email-Blasts)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /store/$1 [R=301,L]
```